# Android Debug Bridge adb shell

Tags: android, windows, shell, batch-file, adb

I want to know whether it is possible to run /system/bin/sh android shell commands remotely from windows by writing a batch file or any other way.

when I write a batch file it's not executing any commands after "adb shell" (the control is shifting to /system/bin/sh and I cannot run any commands from here)

what I need is to know if there is a way to give commands to this shell running on my android device without typing them manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of sending the following lines to the input buffer for adb shell to process.

```
@echo off
(
  echo ls
  echo cd sdcard
  echo ls
  echo exit
) | adb shell
```

Comment: Can you help me on sending a keystroke from batch file as well ?

Comment: I am running a C program which is waiting on getchar() to get a key press from keyboard , I want to make pressing of keyboard from batch file

Comment: As long as you do not flush the buffer in your program, piping the character needed should work. Example using xcopy: `echo f|xcopy ...`